# Does present perfect with "stolen" mean it is not stolen for ever?

Tags: present-perfect

> By the way, will you get other copies of the new lumpy releases as the
>   first batch [**have been stolen** / **was stolen**]?

If I choose present perfect does it mean that there might be a possibility that the items in the stolen batch might be recovered?

If I choose past simple, does that mean that I don't hope for the records to be recovered?

What is the best choice here and why?

Comment: Just so you know, "was stolen" is not simply the simple past. It is passive voice in the simple past. My point is, this is not simply a matter of tenses. It's a matter of active voice versus passive voice, we could not just use "stole" here, we would have to use "was stolen".

Comment: The point about the present perfect tense is that it is a 'compound tense' combining past and present, whereas the simple past is purely a past tense. With the present perfect tense the past situation is seen as having some kind of current relevance, relevance to the present; perhaps the theft has recently occurred and is still being investigated. By contrast, the simple past tense does not express any such relationship;  it simply refers to a past event that may even have occurred some time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I choose present perfect does it mean that there might be a possibility that the items in the stolen batch might be recovered?

Present perfect for verb X means we are talking about past events in time order and that something else happened between X and now.

If that "something else" can be evaluated to mean "searching for" or "expect to find" then "have been stolen" can imply it will be recovered, whereas "was stolen" won't have that implication since it doesn't take that additional "event" into account.

So your context has to create that implied event, and if it does, then present perfect can imply that.

> My money has been stolen, but I talked to the security guys and they are looking at the camera. (We have an implied event of "I'm doing things to search for the thief" here.)
>
> My money was stolen, but I talked to the security guys and they are looking at the camera. (No implied event here, it sounds like you gave up trying to recover it but just talked to the security guys for the heck of it.)

Answer (score 1):

From the options you have given, I would go with:

> ...as the first batch was stolen.

because I'm not sure that saying:

> ...as the first batch have been stolen.

is technically correct. As the batch is a singular item (albeit made up of multiple constituent parts), I would instead say:

> ...as the first batch **has** been stolen.

I would use "have been stolen" when referring explicitly to multiple items, so for example:

> All of the widgets in the first batch have been stolen.

as opposed to:

> The first batch of widgets was stolen.

Perhaps someone else with formal English language skills far beyond mine will be able to confirm whether "as the first batch have been stolen" is technically/grammatically correct or not, but it's not what I would use as a native English speaker in the UK.

Comment: ok for has been stolen but my question is more on the choice of the tense present perfect or past simple

Answer (score 1):

A British English speaker would prefer using the Present Perfect tense. The second clause is in the **passive voice**

> 1. By the way, will you get other copies of the new lumpy releases as the first batch **has been stolen**?

This can be rewritten in the Active Voice

- By the way, will you get other copies of the new lumpy releases as someone **has stolen** the first batch.

The Present Perfect is also used to express an action completed in an indefinite time in the  past. If the speaker mentions *when* the theft occurred, the Simple Past should be used.

2. By the way, ... as the first batch **was stolen** last Monday?

   - By the way, ... as someone **stole** the first batch last Monday? (Active Voice)
3. By the way, ... as the first batch **was stolen**?

An American English speaker would probably opt for the Simple Past (3.), regardless of whether a time expression was used or not. The action clearly happened and **ended** in an unspecific moment in the past.

Either way, using the Simple Past or the Present Perfect are BOTH correct, and they do *not* imply or suggest in any way that the stolen goods will be recovered one day. On the other hand, the speaker does not exclude the possibility that one day the stolen batch will be returned to the owners, anything is possible, nor does he exclude the possibility of a second theft.

*a) My home was burgled ten years ago*, and *b) My home has been bugled once*  does not mean it can't happen again.

> The Present Perfect tense [...]. In fact, the structure of the Present Perfect is very simple. The problems come with the use of the tense. In addition, there are some differences in usage between British and American English.
>
> - We often use the Present Perfect to talk about **experience from the past**. We are not interested in when you did something. We only want to know if you did it
> - We also use the Present Perfect **to talk about a change**, or **new information**
>
> [Americans do use the Present Perfect but less than British speakers. Americans often use the Past Simple tense instead.](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verb-tenses_present-perfect_u.htm) An American might say "Did you have lunch?", where a British person would say "Have you had lunch?"
>
> - We often use the Present Perfect to talk about **a continuing situation**. This is a state that started in the past and continues in the present (and will probably continue into the future).

My brief summary was taken from *English Club.com*

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

By the way, will you get other copies of the new lumpy releases as the first batch had been stolen?

> I would use [past perfect](https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-present-perfect-and-past-perfect-in-english/).
>
> I do not anticipate recovery nor am I still hoping to recover the stolen batch. In fact, they are already out of sight, out of mind.

Long answer:

By the way, will you get other copies of the new lumpy releases as the first batch has been stolen?

> Yes, you are correct, I would anticipate recovery with [present perfect](https://www.espressoenglish.net/difference-between-present-perfect-and-past-perfect-in-english/).

By the way, will you get other copies of the new lumpy releases as the first batch was stolen?

> No, this does not mean that I don't hope for the records to be recovered. It just means I'm not sure if and when the stolen batch will be recovered, but I still have hope.
>
> By the way, this is not simply the simple past. It is [passive voice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113366/present-perfect-vs-passive-voice) in the simple past. My point is, passive voice is needed here, instead of just the simple past "stole".

Comment: So no difference in terms of meaning between past simple or present perfect perfect in this case!

Comment: @user5577 There _is_ a difference in my certainty of recovery. My certainty would be higher with present perfect than it would be with the simple past passive voice.